# Executing Linux Command in Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, unix, command-line

I'm trying to execute the following Command in Java in order to kill the spawned process of bash script which is executed through java :

```
kill $(pgrep -P $(pgrep -P 5537))
```

I'm using apache Commons Exec Commandline to build the Command but it's no different to using ProcessBuilder here. So here is what I have so far:

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("bash");
cmdLine.addArgument("-c");
cmdLine.addArgument("kill $(pgrep -P $(pgrep -P "+pid+"))");
```

I get the error

```
bash: $'kill 7940\n7941\n7942\n7943': Command not found.
```

Normally I would now try to get the newlines out of the Command but it also doesn't work to kill just a single process because then I get the error :

```
bash: kill 7980: Command not found.
```

One the one hand I need to use bash to use the variables and on the other hand I can't use it because kill can't be executed with it...

Comment: How are you going to programmatically fetch the pid and give it to a Java file? That's the first thing to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly `kill -9 pidnumber`

Why would you need the bash variables? when java gives you strings to store variables?

Thirdly why not try `System.Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` ?

Also do you have permissions to kill the task? tried `sudo kill -9 pid`?

Comment: why use java variables when I can use bash variables? I would have to execute runtime.exec serveral times if I used java variables. Anyway  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","kill $(pgrep -P $(pgrep -P "+pid+"))"}); did it for me thanks ;)